# Question on Number theory to find sum value of n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S_n = n^2 + 20n + 12$, $n$ a positive integer. How do I get the sum of all possible values of $n$ for
which $S_n$ is a perfect square?

Comment: Thats a quadratic for x so where is the problem

Comment: Well, this can be written as a difference of two squares pretty easily, and then rearranged into a Pythagorean triple, for example. Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$n^2+20n+12=(n+a)^2\iff n=\dfrac{a^2-12}{2a-10}$$

So, $a$ must be even $=2b$(say)

$$\implies n=\dfrac{4b^2-12}{2(2b)-10}=\dfrac{b^2-3}{2b-5}$$

Now if integer $d$ divides $2b-5,b^2-3$

$d$ must divide $2(b^2-3)-b(2b-5)=5b-6$

$d$ must divide $2(5b-6)-5(2b-5)=13$

A necessary condition for $(2b-5)|(b^2-3)$  is $(2b-5)\mid13$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Please explain why $a$ must be even?

Comment: @Ayushakj, $2(a-5)$ is even the numerator has to be even

Comment: $(2b−5)∣13$ in this we will get fractional values (except one), I think.So it will be correct.

Comment: @Ayushakj, You could start with $d$ divides both $a^2-12,2a-10$ as well to find $(a-5)|13$  Yes, $2b-5$ must be $\pm1,\pm13$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: complete the square in $(n+10-x)(n+10+x) = (n+10)^2  - x^2 = \ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

As $(n+2)^2<n^2+20n+12<(n+10)^2$ and $20n+12$ is even the only 3 cases  are to be considered

$n^2+20n+12=(n+4)^2, \ \ n^2+20n+12=(n+6)^2,\ \ n^2+20n+12=(n+8)^2$